# Can't git clone openshift application

Tags: git, openshift

I created an OpenShift application from the web console and a private/public keys pair with `rhc setup`.

Now I'm trying to clone the source code with:

```
git clone ssh://571f385a7628e1161a000080@test-acasaccia.rhcloud.com/~/git/test.git/
```

(URL copied from from the console).

The `git clone` fails with the following message:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname test-acasaccia.rhcloud.com: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: give us the command you use; probably there is an error in your command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all check to see if you have a connection to the machine.

If putty is not able to connect than you have a connection problems.
I assume its a DNS issue and once you will resolve it you will be able to clone.

Comment: With this command the error changed to: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname test-acasaccia.rhcloud.com:~: Name or service not known`

Comment: Ok, are you able to connect to the machine without git? putty./terminal/ssh etc?

Comment: Putty is giving `host does not exist` error. Is it a DNS issue?

Comment: Looks like it. If you cant connect to the machine via ssh you will not be able to clone as well. The problem is with your connection and not with git.

Comment: At least you found the problem, now you need to find out if its a proxy/DNS etc

Comment: Like you i assume its a DNS problem.